# Add prefix to a macro that calls printf

Tags: c, macros, printf, c-preprocessor, variadic-functions

Having this `#define PRINTF(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)` I want to create a macro that calls `PRINTF` but that adds prefix to the printed string, for example:

```
#define PRINTF_P(<args>) PRINTF(<whatever>) 

// let's suppose that the desired prefix is 'prefix - '
PRINTF_P("Hello world\n");
PRINTF_P("Hello world, num = %d\n", 25);

// Result:
prefix - Hello world
prefix - Hello world, num = 20
```

How can I do this?

### What I have tried

The following works for calls like `PRINTF_P("string with argument %d\n", arg)`, but it doesn't for calls like `PRINTF_P("string with no argument\n");

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define PRINTF(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)

#define A(fmt, ...) fmt
#define B(fmt, ...) __VA_ARGS__

#define PRINTF_P(...) printf( "prefix - " A(__VA_ARGS__), B(__VA_ARGS__))

int main(void)
{   
    PRINTF_P("No number\n");        // This fails
    PRINTF_P("Number = %d\n", 20);  // This works
    return 0;
}
```

### EDIT

I'm referring only to the case of string literals, not `char *`.

Answer (score 2):

It is as easy as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define PRINTF(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PRINTF_P(...) printf( "prefix " __VA_ARGS__)

int main(void)
{
    PRINTF("No number\n");
    PRINTF("Number = %d\n", 20);


    PRINTF_P("No number\n");
    PRINTF_P("Number = %d\n", 20);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It is as easy as:"  Oh?  Now try `char *str = ...; PRINTF_P( str );`

Comment: @AndrewHenle My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72162297/34824) handles that situation.

Comment: Yes, `PRINTF_P(var)` doesn't work, but this still may not be a bad solution. The usual convention for client code is to use a literal format string. You can make gcc warn you about non-literals with `-Wformat-nonliteral` and the macro solution gives you the usual format checking out of the box. (Yes, you can get such checking for functions, too, but you must explicitly write gcc function attributes or SAL annotations.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you should use a macro at all.

Just write an encapsulating function using `vprintf` and variable args.

[***IDEOne Link***](https://ideone.com/Xz9PAK)

```
#include <stdarg.h>
int prefix_printf(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    printf("prefix ");                // Print desired Prefix

    va_list args;                     // Declare a variable for the "..."
    va_start(args, fmt);              // Initialize the args as everything after parameter "fmt"

    int result = vprintf(fmt, args);  // Variant of printf that accepts args instead of ...
    va_end(args);                     // Clean up the args
    return result;                    // Return the same value printf would've returned
}


int main(void) {
    prefix_printf("No number\n");
    prefix_printf("Number = %d\n", 20);
    return 0;
}
```

### Result:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0.01s 5536KB
prefix No number
prefix Number = 20
```